# asian option – exotic option – real data, authentic examples?

Tags: options, market-data, option-data

I would be pleased if any of You can give me the real example of an *asian option* (or other *exotic option*) that is being traded or that is offered by some institution.

I have been searching the whole internet, but only what I can find is how to price asian options, and I want to compare those methods with a real situation.

Best regards,

Pablo

Comment: Do you want a sample term sheet? Is that all?

Comment: The article ["The Performance of Option Pricing Models on Hedging Exotic Options"](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/228923650_The_Performance_of_Option_Pricing_Models_on_Hedging_Exotic_Options) by Yunbi An & W. Suo (2003) may help you.

Answer (score 1):

CME Group offers exchange-traded Asian-style options on WTI Crude Oil Futures, among other underlying products:

http://www.cmegroup.com/trading/energy/crude-oil/west-texas-intermediate-wti-crude-oil-calendar-swap-futures_contractSpecs_options.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will find any data on that. Asian option are OTC traded, and embedded in contracts between 2 parties.

Comment: I'm not so sure, I think it's traded by CMEGroup.